# Python: replacing fields from another lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way in Python 3.x to replace fields into lists using another file.

```
A = ['RIS, AS, 1, 2, 3', 
     'RIS, FW, 10, 20, 30', 
     'RIS, QW, 100, 200, 300']

B = ['VEQ','1','map','E','cap',]


B[field3-map] replaced with A[field2]
```

`B[field5-cap] replaced with A[field3]`

.. other fields of 'B' will remain same.

I have already tried as shown in [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-replace-sublist-with-other-in-list/), to read each list inside 'A' variable, and replace with required fields into 'B', but it didn't work.

Trying to get output as below:

```
'VEQ','1','AS','E','1'
'VEQ','1','FW','E','10'
'VEQ','1','QW','E','100'
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want to accomplish but I can't. Could you please give a more clear example? I can't figura out the mapping you need. Sorry.

Comment: Give a [mcve] with more information than *"didn't work"*.

Comment: i need to print B replacing field2, field 3 from A... since A has 3 lists.. B will be of 3 lines each replaced at corresponding locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code works...

```
A = ['RIS, AS, 1, 2, 3', 
     'RIS, FW, 10, 20, 30', 
     'RIS, QW, 100, 200, 300']

B = ['VEQ','1','map','E','cap',]


for x in map(lambda x: str.split(x, ','), A):
    retval = B[:]
    retval[2] = A[1]
    retval[4] = A[2]
    print(retval)
```